# Linux & C++: Easy way to exchange objects between two processes

Tags: c++, linux, object, exchange-server

I would like to know what is the easiest way (amongst various alternatives) to exchange objects (or some data) between two linux-based systems.

It appears socket-programming could be a choice, but I have not done it earlier so I am not sure if it is the best way. Could anyone point me to a reference please?

TIA,
Sviiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [Boost IPC](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/interprocess.html), as well as [Google's Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html). Or just generally, read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60649/cross-platform-ipc) concerning platform independent IPC, it's not exactly what you want, but should give you some good pointers.

Comment: Protocol Buffers look very exciting! Thanks for the links, roe. They are most useful. :D

Answer (score 0):

there are several way to implement inter process communication in Linux
it depended on what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish 
see [here](http://www.linuxhq.com/guides/LPG/node7.html) for details :

Comment: Thanks Alon. But it looks like these are for a single-box tools and not between two different linux boxes. I could be wrong, but I will read all the links. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

For exchanging objects between programs on the same or different computers I would use 
[SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) or [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture)

Comment: I've never used but seems to be interesting. Will check it out. Thanks Puppe. :)