# Is there any C\C++ Cross-platform library for sharing data between app's?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, sharing

Is there any C\C++ Cross-platform library for sharing data between app's?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? Exchanging messages?

Comment: See [cross platform IPC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60649/cross-platform-ipc)

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "data" and "sharing" in you question. As it's too broad to really answer effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google's Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) might fit the bill.

Answer (score 8):

Obviously the answer to your question is.. Yes there are many cross platform libs for sharing data between applications. For example Boost has [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), for data storage and reading, and [Boost Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/interprocess.html), for in-memory data sharing.

Answer (score 3):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 2):

A cross platform library with a lot of OS abstractions is [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html). You can look in the samples that come along with the tarball for detailed examples.

Comment: I'm looking for boost libraries that implement some of the ACE Proactor/Reactor stuff.  Anyone comes across anything?

Comment: And is it a bad sign that www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html is permanently burned into my brain?

Answer (score 1):

For messaging ?

- Json (simple and easy)
- Google Protocol Buffers (tad more complicated, thus more powerful)
- XML (widely deployed, but you don't want it)

Or did you mean more than just the protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

UDP or TCP.

Open a port using sockets.  You'll find numerous examples of such when you google "c sockets"