# DBusWatch and DBusTimeout examples

Tags: c, dbus

I need to write an application in C for asynchronous sending and reading messages on the dbus message queue. I've read that for doing that I should use the `DBusWatch` and `DBusTimeout` objects that the connection provides, but I cannot find an example of how to use these anywhere...

For the moment i use [`dbus_connection_read_write_dispatch`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusConnection.html#ga580d8766c23fe5f49418bc7d87b67dc6) in order to do that, but I've read that it is not recommended for asynchronous operations, so I'll have to switch to creating my own `main loop` and using it...

The closest answer to my question was this one:

http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dbus/2007-September/008555.html ,

suggesting to look through the dbus-gmain.c file, which I did, but all I found there was a call of the [`dbus_connection_set_watch_functions`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusConnection.html#gaebf031eb444b4f847606aa27daa3d8e6) and [`dbus_connection_set_timeout_functions`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusConnection.html#gab3cbc68eec427e9ce1783b25d44fe93c), with other functions as parameters - should I overwrite those functions? Should I use them as they are?

I simply cannot figure out how to use these in order to read and write something to the dbus message queue...

Any idea would be more than welcome...

Comment: Note to myself: The 008555.html has been gone for ages, but here it is via archive.org for posterity:

"Your best bet is to look at examples, such as
dbus_connection_setup_with_g_main() in dbus-glib, or the equivalent in
Qt.

Havoc"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's something I wrote some time ago. I removed application specific code, you should just add your snippets where you handle DBus messages meant for your application and that should be it.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <dbus/dbus.h>

struct dbus_ctx {
    DBusConnection *conn;
    struct event_base *evbase;
    struct event dispatch_ev;
    void *extra;
};

static void dispatch(int fd, short ev, void *x)
{
    struct dbus_ctx *ctx = x;
    DBusConnection *c = ctx->conn;

    logger(LOG_DEBUG "dispatching\n");

    while (dbus_connection_get_dispatch_status(c) == DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS)
        dbus_connection_dispatch(c);
}

static void handle_dispatch_status(DBusConnection *c,
                                   DBusDispatchStatus status, void *data)
{
    struct dbus_ctx *ctx = data;

    logger(LOG_DEBUG "new dbus dispatch status: %d\n", status);

    if (status == DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS) {
        struct timeval tv = {
            .tv_sec = 0,
            .tv_usec = 0,
        };
        event_add(&ctx->dispatch_ev, &tv);
    }
}

static void handle_watch(int fd, short events, void *x)
{
    struct dbus_ctx *ctx = x;
    struct DBusWatch *watch = ctx->extra;

    unsigned int flags = 0;
    if (events & EV_READ)
        flags |= DBUS_WATCH_READABLE;
    if (events & EV_WRITE)
        flags |= DBUS_WATCH_WRITABLE;
    /*if (events & HUP)
        flags |= DBUS_WATCH_HANGUP;
    if (events & ERR)
        flags |= DBUS_WATCH_ERROR;*/

    logger(LOG_DEBUG "got dbus watch event fd=%d watch=%p ev=%d\n",
           fd, watch, events);
    if (dbus_watch_handle(watch, flags) == FALSE)
        logger(LOG_ERROR "dbus_watch_handle() failed\n");

    handle_dispatch_status(ctx->conn, DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS, ctx);
}

static dbus_bool_t add_watch(DBusWatch *w, void *data)
{
    if (!dbus_watch_get_enabled(w))
        return TRUE;

    struct dbus_ctx *ctx = data;
    ctx->extra = w;

    int fd = dbus_watch_get_unix_fd(w);
    unsigned int flags = dbus_watch_get_flags(w);
    short cond = EV_PERSIST;
    if (flags & DBUS_WATCH_READABLE)
        cond |= EV_READ;
    if (flags & DBUS_WATCH_WRITABLE)
        cond |= EV_WRITE;

    struct event *event = event_new(ctx->evbase, fd, cond, handle_watch, ctx);
    if (!event)
        return FALSE;

    event_add(event, NULL);

    dbus_watch_set_data(w, event, NULL);

    logger(LOG_DEBUG "added dbus watch fd=%d watch=%p cond=%d\n", fd, w, cond);
    return TRUE;
}

static void remove_watch(DBusWatch *w, void *data)
{
    struct event *event = dbus_watch_get_data(w);

    if (event)
        event_free(event);

    dbus_watch_set_data(w, NULL, NULL);

    logger(LOG_DEBUG "removed dbus watch watch=%p\n", w);
}

static void toggle_watch(DBusWatch *w, void *data)
{
    logger(LOG_DEBUG "toggling dbus watch watch=%p\n", w);

    if (dbus_watch_get_enabled(w))
        add_watch(w, data);
    else
        remove_watch(w, data);
}

static void handle_timeout(int fd, short ev, void *x)
{
    struct dbus_ctx *ctx = x;
    DBusTimeout *t = ctx->extra;

    logger(LOG_DEBUG "got dbus handle timeout event %p\n", t);

    dbus_timeout_handle(t);
}

static dbus_bool_t add_timeout(DBusTimeout *t, void *data)
{
    struct dbus_ctx *ctx = data;

    if (!dbus_timeout_get_enabled(t))
        return TRUE;

    logger(LOG_DEBUG "adding timeout %p\n", t);

    struct event *event = event_new(ctx->evbase, -1, EV_TIMEOUT|EV_PERSIST,
                                    handle_timeout, t);
    if (!event) {
        logger(LOG_ERROR "failed to allocate new event for timeout\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    int ms = dbus_timeout_get_interval(t);
    struct timeval tv = {
        .tv_sec = ms / 1000,
        .tv_usec = (ms % 1000) * 1000,
    };
    event_add(event, &tv);

    dbus_timeout_set_data(t, event, NULL);

    return TRUE;
}

static void remove_timeout(DBusTimeout *t, void *data)
{
    struct event *event = dbus_timeout_get_data(t);

    logger(LOG_DEBUG "removing timeout %p\n", t);

    event_free(event);

    dbus_timeout_set_data(t, NULL, NULL);
}

static void toggle_timeout(DBusTimeout *t, void *data)
{
    logger(LOG_DEBUG "toggling timeout %p\n", t);

    if (dbus_timeout_get_enabled(t))
        add_timeout(t, data);
    else
        remove_timeout(t, data);
}

static DBusHandlerResult handle_nameownerchanged(DBusMessage *message,
                                                 void *data)
{
    struct dbus_ctx *ctx = data;
    char *name, *old, *new;
    if (dbus_message_get_args(message, NULL,
                              DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &name,
                              DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &old,
                              DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &new,
                              DBUS_TYPE_INVALID) == FALSE) {
        logger(LOG_ERROR "spurious NameOwnerChanged signal\n");
        return DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_NOT_YET_HANDLED;
    }
    logger(LOG_DEBUG "dbus NameOwnerChanged %s -> %s\n", old, new);

    if (new[0] != '\0')
        return DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_NOT_YET_HANDLED;

    /* XXX handle disconnecting clients */

    return DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_NOT_YET_HANDLED;
}

static DBusHandlerResult msg_filter(DBusConnection *connection,
                                    DBusMessage *message, void *data)
{
    if (dbus_message_is_signal(message, DBUS_INTERFACE_DBUS,
                               "NameOwnerChanged"))
        return handle_nameownerchanged(message, data);

    logger(LOG_DEBUG "got dbus message %d %s -> %s %s/%s/%s %s\n",
           dbus_message_get_type(message),
           dbus_message_get_sender(message),
           dbus_message_get_destination(message),
           dbus_message_get_path(message),
           dbus_message_get_interface(message),
           dbus_message_get_member(message),
           dbus_message_get_type(message) == DBUS_MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR ?
           dbus_message_get_error_name(message) : "");

    return DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_NOT_YET_HANDLED;
}

static void unregister_func(DBusConnection *connection, void *data)
{
}

static DBusHandlerResult message_func(DBusConnection *connection,
                                      DBusMessage *message, void *data)
{
    struct dbus_ctx *ctx = data;

    logger(LOG_DEBUG "got dbus message sent to %s %s %s\n",
           dbus_message_get_destination(message),
           dbus_message_get_interface(message),
           dbus_message_get_path(message));

    /* XXX handle DBus message */

    return DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_HANDLED;
}

static DBusObjectPathVTable dbus_vtable = {
    .unregister_function = unregister_func,
    .message_function = message_func,
};

struct dbus_ctx *dbus_init(struct event_base *eb)
{
    DBusConnection *conn = NULL;
    struct dbus_ctx *ctx = calloc(1, sizeof(struct dbus_ctx));
    if (!ctx) {
        logger_perror("can't allocate dbus_ctx\n");
        goto out;
    }

    conn = dbus_bus_get_private(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, NULL);
    if (conn == NULL) {
        logger(LOG_ERROR "failed to get bus\n");
        goto out;
    }

    dbus_connection_set_exit_on_disconnect(conn, FALSE);

    ctx->conn = conn;
    ctx->evbase = eb;
    event_assign(&ctx->dispatch_ev, eb, -1, EV_TIMEOUT, dispatch, ctx);

    if (!dbus_connection_set_watch_functions(conn, add_watch, remove_watch,
                                             toggle_watch, ctx, NULL)) {
        logger(LOG_ERROR "dbus_connection_set_watch_functions() failed\n");
        goto out;
    }

    if (!dbus_connection_set_timeout_functions(conn, add_timeout,
                                               remove_timeout, toggle_timeout,
                                               ctx, NULL)) {
        logger(LOG_ERROR "dbus_connection_set_timeout_functions() failed\n");
        goto out;
    }

    if (dbus_connection_add_filter(conn, msg_filter, ctx, NULL) == FALSE) {
        logger(LOG_ERROR "dbus_connection_add_filter() failed\n");
        goto out;
    }

    dbus_connection_set_dispatch_status_function(conn, handle_dispatch_status,
                                                 ctx, NULL);

    char match[256];
    snprintf(match,
             sizeof(match),
             "type='signal',interface='%s',member='NameOwnerChanged'",
             DBUS_INTERFACE_DBUS);
    DBusError error;
    dbus_error_init(&error);
    dbus_bus_add_match(conn, match, &error);
    if (dbus_error_is_set(&error)) {
        logger(LOG_ERROR "dbus_bus_add_match() %s failed: %s\n",
               "NameOwnerChanged", error.message);
        dbus_error_free(&error);
        goto out;
    }

    snprintf(match,
             sizeof(match),
             "type='signal',interface='%s',member='%s'",
             GNP_IPC_INTERFACE, GNP_IPC_SIGNAL_DELIVER_SA);
    dbus_error_init(&error);
    dbus_bus_add_match(conn, match, &error);
    if (dbus_error_is_set(&error)) {
        logger(LOG_ERROR "dbus_bus_add_match() %s failed: %s\n",
               GNP_IPC_SIGNAL_DELIVER_SA, error.message);
        dbus_error_free(&error);
        goto out;
    }

    if (dbus_connection_register_object_path(conn, GNP_IPC_PATH, &dbus_vtable,
                                             ctx) != TRUE) {
        logger(LOG_ERROR "failed to register object path\n");
        goto out;
    }

    return ctx;

out:
    if (conn) {
        dbus_connection_close(conn);
        dbus_connection_unref(conn);
    }
    if (ctx)
        free(ctx);
    return NULL;
}

void dbus_close(struct dbus_ctx *ctx)
{
    if (ctx && ctx->conn) {
        dbus_connection_flush(ctx->conn);
        dbus_connection_close(ctx->conn);
        dbus_connection_unref(ctx->conn);
        event_del(&ctx->dispatch_ev);
    }
    if (ctx)
        free(ctx);
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention, this one uses libevent. You can also run dbus message handling in a separate thread if that fits your architecture better, that requires direct dispatching of dbus messages.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for posting this.  Is it mandatory to register watch functions in order to receive messages from the connection?  And is there a good resource you can recommend, besides the DBus documentation.  Something with C/C++ examples like yours?

Comment: Yes, you need to handle watch events. There are not that many resources I'm aware of for C/C++, unfortunately, when I had to implement a DBus client I was browsing through source code of projects doing similar stuff.

Comment: Is it possible for asynchronous sending and reading messages in D-bus using the function calls https://pastebin.com/4E6XB3qb ?
 
I didn't understand why dbus_connection_set_dispatch_status_function(), dbus_connection_set_watch_functions() and dbus_connection_set_timeout_functions() functions are required?

My understanding is, if we register object path(i.e DBusObjectPathVTable) then d-bus daemon will call "message_function" of vtable when any message received for the connection. Please let me know if this understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Idx's code and examples from other sources (mainly example by Matthew Johnson and Will Ware), here is a synchronous event handling sample with a mainloop on select(). Just run in two terminals to see how events are passing around.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE   /* for pipe2 in unistd.h */

#include <dbus/dbus.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>   /* for pipe2 */
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>    /* for O_NONBLOCK */
#include <sys/time.h> /* for gettimeofday */
#include <limits.h>   /* for INT_MAX */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* chgevt: 
 * when watch/timeout changes, pass a chgevt via a pipe to 
 * the selector loop so the loop will return from select() and 
 * react to the dbus change immediately. only need this when a new 
 * watch/timeout is added or enabled. when a watch/timeout is removed 
 * or disabled, immediate response is not needed. 
 * 
 * when running in single thread because those changes happen only 
 * in stage 2 of the selector loop, this chgevt path is not necessary. 
 * if running in multiple threads, e.g. calling dbus sending from 
 * another thread, then the path would be essential. 
 */

/* events */
#define CHGEVT_ADD_WATCH   (1)
#define CHGEVT_ADD_TIMEOUT (2)

static int watched_chgevt_fds[2] = {0,0}; /* [0] read, [1] write */

static void watched_chgevt_setup() {
    int rc = pipe2(watched_chgevt_fds, O_NONBLOCK);
    if ( rc != 0 ) watched_chgevt_fds[0] = watched_chgevt_fds[1] = 0;
}
static void watched_chgevt_send(int evt) {
    if ( watched_chgevt_fds[1] ) write(watched_chgevt_fds[1], &evt, 1); 
}
static int watched_chgevt_get() { 
    int rc = 0;
    if ( watched_chgevt_fds[0] ) { 
        if ( (rc = read(watched_chgevt_fds[0], &rc, 1)) < 0 ) {
            if ( errno != EAGAIN ) {
                perror("watched_chgevt_fds pipe failed");
                watched_chgevt_fds[0] = watched_chgevt_fds[1] = 0;
            }
            rc = 0;
        }
    }
    return rc;
}

/* watch */
static DBusWatch * watched_watch = NULL;
static int watched_rd_fd = 0;
static int watched_wr_fd = 0;

static dbus_bool_t add_watch(DBusWatch *w, void *data)
{
    if (!dbus_watch_get_enabled(w))
        return TRUE;

    int fd = dbus_watch_get_unix_fd(w);
    unsigned int flags = dbus_watch_get_flags(w);
    int old_rd_fd = watched_rd_fd;
    int old_wr_fd = watched_wr_fd;
    if (flags & DBUS_WATCH_READABLE)
        watched_rd_fd = fd;
    if (flags & DBUS_WATCH_WRITABLE)
        watched_wr_fd = fd;
    watched_watch = w;

    printf(" WATCH:    add dbus watch fd=%d watch=%p rd_fd=%d/%d wr_fd=%d/%d\n", 
           fd, w, watched_rd_fd, old_rd_fd, watched_wr_fd, old_wr_fd);
    watched_chgevt_send( CHGEVT_ADD_WATCH ); 
    return TRUE;
}
static void remove_watch(DBusWatch *w, void *data)
{
    watched_watch = NULL;
    watched_rd_fd = 0;
    watched_wr_fd = 0;
    printf(" WATCH:    remove dbus watch watch=%p\n", w);
}
static void toggle_watch(DBusWatch *w, void *data)
{
    printf(" WATCH:    toggle dbus watch watch=%p\n", w);
    if (dbus_watch_get_enabled(w))
        add_watch(w, data);
    else
        remove_watch(w, data);
}

/* timeout */
static DBusTimeout * watched_timeout = NULL;
static struct timeval watched_timeout_start_tv = { 0, 0 };
                             /* at which timeout is enabled */
static unsigned int watched_timeout_setv = 0; /* set value */
static unsigned int watched_timeout_lastv = 0; /* last trigger */

#define TIMEOUT_MAX_MS ( 1000 * 1000 ) /* 1000 sec */
#define TIMEOUT_MOD_MS ( 8 * TIMEOUT_MAX_MS ) /* 8000 sec */
               /* note: last_trigger is 0 to 7999 sec. 
                *       next_timeout is 0 to 8999 sec.
                */
#define TIME_TV_TO_MS(x) /* convert a timeval to 0-to-7999 ms */ \
               ( (x.tv_sec%(TIMEOUT_MOD_MS/1000))*1000 + \
                 x.tv_usec/1000 )

static dbus_bool_t add_timeout(DBusTimeout *t, void *data)
{
    if (!dbus_timeout_get_enabled(t))
        return TRUE;

    int ms = dbus_timeout_get_interval(t);
    if ( ms < 0 || ms > TIMEOUT_MAX_MS ) {
        ms = TIMEOUT_MAX_MS;
        if ( ms < 0 || ms > INT_MAX/2-1 ) {
            ms = INT_MAX/2-1;
        }
    }
    if ( ms < 1 ) {
        ms = 1; 
    }

    struct timeval tnow = {0,0};
    gettimeofday(&tnow, NULL);
    unsigned int tnowms = TIME_TV_TO_MS(tnow);

    printf(" TIMEOUT: add dbus timeout %p value %u ms\n", t, ms);

    watched_timeout_start_tv = tnow;
    watched_timeout_setv = ms;
    watched_timeout_lastv = tnowms;
    watched_timeout = t;

    watched_chgevt_send( CHGEVT_ADD_TIMEOUT ); 
    return TRUE;
}
static void remove_timeout(DBusTimeout *t, void *data)
{
    printf(" TIMEOUT: remove timeout %p\n", t);
    watched_timeout = NULL;
    struct timeval tv = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = 0, };
    watched_timeout_start_tv = tv;
    watched_timeout_setv = 0;
    watched_timeout_lastv = 0;
}
static void toggle_timeout(DBusTimeout *t, void *data)
{
    printf(" TIMEOUT: toggle timeout %p\n", t);
    if (dbus_timeout_get_enabled(t))
        add_timeout(t, data);
    else
        remove_timeout(t, data);
}

/* the selector function */
 /* receive */
 static int dbus_selector_process_recv(DBusConnection* conn, int iswaiting_rpcreply,
                                       DBusPendingCall** pendingargptr);

 /* send rpc request */
 static int dbus_selector_process_post_send(DBusConnection* conn, char * param,
                                            DBusPendingCall** pendingargptr);
 /* receive rpc reply, called by process_recv() */
 static int dbus_selector_process_post_reply(DBusConnection* conn,
                                             DBusPendingCall** pendingargptr );

/* selector */
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <time.h>
static unsigned int lastregtime = 0;

int dbus_selector(char *param, int altsel )
{
   DBusConnection* conn;
   DBusError err;
   int ret = 1; /* default fail */

    watched_chgevt_setup();


        char * destarray[4] = { "test.selector.server", "test.selector.client",
                                "test.unknown.user1", "test.unknown.user2" };
        char * deststr = destarray[0];
        if ( altsel != 0 ) {
            deststr = destarray[1];
            lastregtime = time(NULL);
        }

   printf("Accepting method calls and signals\n");

   // initialise the error
   dbus_error_init(&err);

   // connect to the bus and check for errors
   conn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &err);
   if (dbus_error_is_set(&err)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Connection Error (%s)\n", err.message);
      dbus_error_free(&err);
   }
   if (NULL == conn) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Connection Null\n");
      return ret; /* ret=1 fail */
   }

   // request our name on the bus and check for errors
   ret = dbus_bus_request_name(conn, deststr /* "test.selector.server" */, 
                               DBUS_NAME_FLAG_REPLACE_EXISTING , &err);
   if (dbus_error_is_set(&err)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Name Error (%s)\n", err.message);
      dbus_error_free(&err);
   }
   if (DBUS_REQUEST_NAME_REPLY_PRIMARY_OWNER != ret) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Not Primary Owner (%d)\n", ret);
      return ret; /* ret=1 fail */
   }

   // add a rule for which messages we want to see
   dbus_bus_add_match(conn, "type='signal',interface='test.signal.Type'", &err); 
                                           // see signals from the given interface
   dbus_connection_flush(conn); /* Note: this would block */
   if (dbus_error_is_set(&err)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Match Error (%s)\n", err.message);
      return ret; /* ret=1 fail */
   }
   printf("Match signal rule sent\n");

    /* setup watch and timeout */
    if (!dbus_connection_set_watch_functions(conn, add_watch, remove_watch,
                                             toggle_watch, NULL, NULL)) {
        printf(" ERROR dbus_connection_set_watch_functions() failed\n");
        return ret; /* ret=1 fail */
    }
    if (!dbus_connection_set_timeout_functions(conn, add_timeout,
                                               remove_timeout, toggle_timeout,
                                               NULL, NULL)) {
        printf(" ERROR dbus_connection_set_timeout_functions() failed\n");
        return ret; /* ret=1 fail */
    }

    /* the selector loop */
    ret = 0; /* default success */
    struct timeval local_to_startv = {0,0}; /* timeout saved locally */
    DBusPendingCall* pending = NULL; /* keep track of the outstanding rpc call */
    while(ret == 0) {

        /* the selector loop stage 1, setup for select() call. 
         * in this stage no dbus watch/timeout change should happen 
         */

        #define DEFAULT_SELECT_LOOP_MS (5500)
        int modified_timeout = 0; /* yes or no */

        fd_set rfds, wfds, efds;
        struct timeval timeoutval = {
                           DEFAULT_SELECT_LOOP_MS/1000, 
                           (DEFAULT_SELECT_LOOP_MS%1000)*1000 };
        int nfds = 1;
        int rc = 0;

        printf("\n");
        FD_ZERO(&rfds); FD_ZERO(&wfds); FD_ZERO(&efds);
        if ( watched_watch != NULL ) {
            if ( watched_rd_fd ) { 
                FD_SET(watched_rd_fd, &rfds);
                FD_SET(watched_rd_fd, &efds);
                if ( nfds <= watched_rd_fd ) { nfds = watched_rd_fd + 1; } 
                printf(" SELECT nfds %d  rdfd %d\n", nfds, watched_rd_fd);
            }
            if ( watched_wr_fd ) { 
                FD_SET(watched_wr_fd, &wfds);
                FD_SET(watched_wr_fd, &efds);
                if ( nfds <= watched_wr_fd ) { nfds = watched_wr_fd + 1; } 
                printf(" SELECT nfds %d  wrfd %d\n", nfds, watched_wr_fd);
            }
        }
        if ( watched_chgevt_fds[0] != 0 ) {
            FD_SET(watched_chgevt_fds[0], &rfds);
            FD_SET(watched_chgevt_fds[0], &efds);
        }

        if ( watched_timeout != NULL ) {
            struct timeval startv = watched_timeout_start_tv;
            unsigned int setv = watched_timeout_setv;
            unsigned int lastv = watched_timeout_lastv;

            struct timeval tnow = {0,0};
            unsigned int tnowms = 0;
            unsigned int toms = 0;
            unsigned int tdiff = 0;

            gettimeofday(&tnow, NULL);
            tnowms = TIME_TV_TO_MS(tnow);

            if ( startv.tv_sec != local_to_startv.tv_sec || 
                 startv.tv_usec != local_to_startv.tv_sec   ) 
            { /* new timeout */
                local_to_startv = startv;
            }
            if ( lastv > tnowms ) {
                tnowms += TIMEOUT_MOD_MS;
            }
            toms = lastv + setv + 1;
                             /* add 1 to make up for rounding loss */
            if ( toms > tnowms ) {
                tdiff = toms - tnowms; /* ms till timeout */
            }
            if ( tdiff < DEFAULT_SELECT_LOOP_MS ) {
                /* revise timeout value */
                timeoutval.tv_sec = tdiff/1000;
                timeoutval.tv_usec = (tdiff%1000)*1000;
                modified_timeout = 1; /* yes */
            }
        }

        if ( modified_timeout ) {
            printf(" SELECT with nfds %d ... modified tiemout %lu.%03lu\n", 
                         nfds, timeoutval.tv_sec, timeoutval.tv_usec/1000);
        } else {
            printf(" SELECT with nfds %d...\n", nfds);
        }

        rc = select(nfds, &rfds, &wfds, &efds, &timeoutval);
        if ( rc < 0 ) {
            printf(" SELECT returned error %d\n", rc);
            break;
        }

        /* the selector loop stage 2, dbus operation. 
         * in this stage dbus watch/timeout could change.
         */

        /* check timeout */
        if ( watched_timeout != NULL ) {
            struct timeval startv = watched_timeout_start_tv;
            unsigned int setv = watched_timeout_setv;
            unsigned int lastv = watched_timeout_lastv;
            struct timeval tnow = {0,0}; unsigned int tnowms = 0, toms = 0;

            gettimeofday(&tnow, NULL);
            tnowms = TIME_TV_TO_MS(tnow);

            if ( startv.tv_sec == local_to_startv.tv_sec && 
                 startv.tv_usec == local_to_startv.tv_sec   ) 
            { /* same timeout */
                if ( lastv > tnowms ) {
                    tnowms += TIMEOUT_MOD_MS;
                }
                toms = lastv + setv + 1;
                             /* add 1 to make up for rounding loss */
                if ( toms >= tnowms ) {
                    watched_timeout_lastv = tnowms%TIMEOUT_MOD_MS;
                    printf(" HANDLING dbus handle timeout %p\n", 
                           watched_timeout);
                    dbus_timeout_handle(watched_timeout);
                    printf(" HANDLING dbus handle timeout %p done\n", 
                           watched_timeout);
                }
            } /* else if not the same timeout as before select() skip for now */
        }

        /* self initiated rpc call */
        if ( altsel ) {
            unsigned int tmnow = time(NULL);
            unsigned int tmdiff = tmnow - lastregtime;
            if ( tmdiff > 10 ) { /* send a rpc evey 10 seconds */
                dbus_selector_process_post_send(conn, param, &pending);
                lastregtime = tmnow;
            }
        }

        /* select() returned no event */
        if ( rc == 0 ) {
            printf(" SELECT returned rc 0 \n");
            continue;
        }

        /* some event happened according to select() */
        printf(" SELECT returned rc %d \n", rc);
        if ( watched_watch != NULL ) {
            if ( watched_rd_fd ) { 
                if ( FD_ISSET(watched_rd_fd, &rfds) ) {
                    printf(" HANDLING calls watch_handle\n");
                    dbus_watch_handle(watched_watch, DBUS_WATCH_READABLE);
                    printf(" HANDLING calls process_recv\n");
                    dbus_selector_process_recv(conn, pending==NULL?0:1,
                                                     &pending);
                    printf(" HANDLING done process_recv\n");
                }
                if ( FD_ISSET(watched_rd_fd, &efds) ) {
                    printf(" HANDLING EXCEPTION with rd fd %d \n",
                           watched_rd_fd);
                }
            }
            if ( watched_wr_fd ) { 
                if ( FD_ISSET(watched_wr_fd, &wfds) ) {
                    dbus_watch_handle(watched_watch, DBUS_WATCH_WRITABLE);
                }
                if ( FD_ISSET(watched_wr_fd, &efds) ) {
                    printf(" HANDLING EXCEPTION with wr fd %d \n",
                           watched_wr_fd);
                }
            }
        }

        /* chgevt pipe */
        if ( watched_chgevt_fds[0] != 0 && FD_ISSET(watched_chgevt_fds[0], &rfds) ) {
            int chgevt = watched_chgevt_get();
            switch (chgevt) {
            case CHGEVT_ADD_WATCH: 
                printf(" HANDLING chgevt 1 consumed \n"); break;
            case CHGEVT_ADD_TIMEOUT: 
                printf(" HANDLING chgevt 2 consumed \n"); break;
            default: 
                printf(" HANDLING chgevt n=%d consumed \n", chgevt); break;
            }
        }
    }
   return ret;
}

static int dbus_selector_process_recv(DBusConnection* conn, int iswaiting_rpcreply,
                                      DBusPendingCall** pendingargptr)
{
    int ret = 1; /* default fail */

    /* remove this call that consumes .1ms because dbus is already read 
     * by dbus_watch_handle():
     * dbus_connection_read_write(conn, 0);
     * 
     * according to dbus_connection_dispatch(): The incoming data buffer 
     * is filled when the connection reads from its underlying transport 
     * (such as a socket). Reading usually happens in dbus_watch_handle() 
     * or dbus_connection_read_write().
     */
    DBusDispatchStatus dispatch_rc = dbus_connection_get_dispatch_status(conn);
    if ( DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS != dispatch_rc ) {
        printf(" ERROR recv no message in queue \n");
    }
    while( DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS == dispatch_rc ) {
        DBusMessage* msg = dbus_connection_borrow_message(conn);
        if ( msg == NULL ) {
            printf(" ERROR recv pending check FAILED: remains but "
                            "no message borrowed. \n");
            break;
        }
        int mtype = dbus_message_get_type(msg);
        if ( iswaiting_rpcreply &&  
             ( mtype == DBUS_MESSAGE_TYPE_METHOD_RETURN ||
               mtype == DBUS_MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR           ) ) {
            printf(" RPC REPLY pending check SUCCESS: received rpc reply \n");
            dbus_connection_return_message(conn, msg);
            dbus_connection_dispatch(conn);
                                  /* dispatch so the received message at the 
                                   * head of queue is passed to the pendingcall
                                   */
            dbus_selector_process_post_reply( conn, pendingargptr );
            printf(" RPC REPLY pending check SUCCESS: processed rpc reply \n");
        } else if ( mtype == DBUS_MESSAGE_TYPE_METHOD_RETURN ) {
            printf(" RECV pending check FAILED: received rpc reply \n");
            dbus_connection_steal_borrowed_message(conn, msg);
            dbus_message_unref(msg);
        } else if ( mtype == DBUS_MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR ) {
            printf(" RECV pending check FAILED: received ERROR \n");
            dbus_connection_steal_borrowed_message(conn, msg);
            dbus_message_unref(msg);
        } else if ( mtype == DBUS_MESSAGE_TYPE_SIGNAL ) {
            printf(" SIGNAL pending check SUCCESS: received and drop \n");
            dbus_connection_steal_borrowed_message(conn, msg);
            dbus_message_unref(msg);
        } else if ( mtype == DBUS_MESSAGE_TYPE_METHOD_CALL ) {
            printf(" RPC RECV check SUCCESS: received rpc call. \n");
            dbus_connection_steal_borrowed_message(conn, msg);
            DBusMessage* reply = NULL;
            do {
                /* craft a reply message */
                DBusMessageIter args;
                dbus_uint32_t serial = 111;
                dbus_bool_t   stat    = TRUE;
                dbus_uint32_t retval1 = 555;
                const char *strval    = "good";
                reply = dbus_message_new_method_return(msg);
                dbus_message_iter_init_append(reply, &args);
                if ( !dbus_message_iter_append_basic(
                                       &args, DBUS_TYPE_BOOLEAN, &stat) ) {
                    printf(" error rpc reply Out Of Memory!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if ( !dbus_message_iter_append_basic(
                                       &args, DBUS_TYPE_UINT32, &retval1) ) {
                    printf(" error rpc reply Out Of Memory!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if ( !dbus_message_iter_append_basic(
                                       &args, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &strval) ) {
                    printf(" error rpc reply Out Of Memory!\n");
                    break;
                }
                if ( !dbus_connection_send(conn, reply, &serial)) {
                    printf(" error rpc reply Out Of Memory!\n");
                    break;
                }
                dbus_connection_flush(conn);
            } while(0);
            if ( reply != NULL ) { dbus_message_unref(reply); }
            if ( msg != NULL ) { /* msg not consumed */
                //dbus_connection_return_message(conn, msg);
                dbus_message_unref(msg);
            }
            ret = 0; /* success */
        } else {
            printf(" error unknown msg type %d \n", mtype);
        }
        dispatch_rc = dbus_connection_get_dispatch_status(conn);
    }
    return ret;
}
static int dbus_selector_process_post_send( DBusConnection* conn, char * param,
                                            DBusPendingCall** pendingargptr)
{ /* mostly a copy of query() */
   DBusMessage* msg = NULL;
   DBusMessageIter args = {0};
   DBusError err = {0};
   DBusPendingCall* pending = NULL;
   int ret = 0;

   * pendingargptr = NULL;

   printf("Calling remote method with %s\n", param);

   // initialiset the errors
   dbus_error_init(&err);

    msg = dbus_message_new_method_call(
                     "test.selector.server", // target for the method call
                     "/test/method/Object", // object to call on
                     "test.method.Type", // interface to call on
                     "Method"); // method name
   if (NULL == msg) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Message Null\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   // append arguments
   dbus_message_iter_init_append(msg, &args);
   if (!dbus_message_iter_append_basic(&args, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &param)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Out Of Memory!\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   // send message and get a handle for a reply
   if (!dbus_connection_send_with_reply (conn, msg, &pending, 300)) { 
                                               // -1 is default timeout
      fprintf(stderr, "Out Of Memory!\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   if (NULL == pending) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Pending Call Null\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   printf("Request Sent\n");

   dbus_connection_flush(conn); /* Note: block until write finishes */
   printf("Request flushed\n");

   // free message
   dbus_message_unref(msg);
   * pendingargptr = pending;
    return ret;
}

static int dbus_selector_process_post_reply( DBusConnection* conn,
                                             DBusPendingCall** pendingargptr )
{
   DBusMessage* msg = NULL;
   DBusMessageIter args = {0};
   dbus_bool_t stat = FALSE;
   dbus_uint32_t level = 0;
   DBusPendingCall* pending = *pendingargptr;

    if ( ! dbus_pending_call_get_completed(pending) ) {
        dbus_pending_call_unref(pending);
        *pendingargptr = NULL;
        fprintf(stderr, " error Reply incomplete\n");
        exit(1);
    }

   // get the reply message
   msg = dbus_pending_call_steal_reply(pending);
   if (NULL == msg) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Reply Null\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   // free the pending message handle
   dbus_pending_call_unref(pending);
    *pendingargptr = NULL;

    /* */
    int validerror = 0;
    { int mtype = dbus_message_get_type(msg);
        if ( mtype == DBUS_MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR ) {
            fprintf(stderr, " error Reply with a valid error detected!\n");
            validerror = 1;
        } else if ( mtype != DBUS_MESSAGE_TYPE_METHOD_RETURN ) {
            fprintf(stderr, " error Reply not a valid return type!"
                    " received message type %d\n", mtype);
        }
    }

   // read the parameters
   if (!dbus_message_iter_init(msg, &args))
      fprintf(stderr, "Message has no arguments!\n");
   else if (DBUS_TYPE_BOOLEAN != dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&args))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Argument is not boolean!\n");
        if (DBUS_TYPE_STRING == dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&args) ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Argument 1 is string!\n");
            if ( validerror ) {
                char * strval = (char*)"<init-unknown>";
                dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&args, &strval);
                if ( strval != NULL && strnlen(strval, 160) < 160 ) {
                    printf("RPC reply arg 0 is c%u %s\n", 160, strval);
                } else {
                    printf("RPC reply arg 0 error \n");
                }
            }
        } else if (DBUS_TYPE_UINT32 == dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&args) ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Argument 1 is uint32!\n");
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Argument 1 is not recognized!\n");
        }
    }
   else
      dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&args, &stat);

   if (!dbus_message_iter_next(&args))
      fprintf(stderr, "Message has too few arguments!\n");
   else if (DBUS_TYPE_UINT32 != dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&args))
      fprintf(stderr, "Argument is not int!\n");
   else
      dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&args, &level);

   printf("Got Reply: %d, %d\n", stat, level);

   // free reply
   dbus_message_unref(msg);

   return 0;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   if (2 > argc) {
      printf ("Syntax: dbus-select-watch [selector|selpost] [<param>]\n");
      return 1;
   }
   char* param = "no cmdline param";
   if (3 <= argc && NULL != argv[2]) param = argv[2];
   if (0 == strncmp(argv[1], "selector", 20))
      dbus_selector(param, 0);
   else if (0 == strncmp(argv[1], "selpost", 20))
      dbus_selector(param, 1);
   else {
      printf ("Syntax: dbus-select-watch [selector|selpost] [<param>]\n");
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have written an example for implementing `main loop` for dbus. I have tested it with `bluez` DBUS API and it works without any problem.

I have removed the bluetooth part of my application. I have used `libevent` to implement `event loop`.

Note: It is in `C++`. You can easily convert it to `C programming language`.

```
#include "dbus-ble/libevent.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <event2/event.h>
#include <event2/util.h>
#include <dbus/dbus.h>

struct watch_handler {
    struct event *ev;
    DBusConnection *dbus_cnx;
    DBusWatch *watch;
};

struct timeout_handler {
    struct event *ev;
    DBusConnection *dbus_cnx;
    DBusTimeout *timeout;
};

static struct event_base *ev_base = nullptr;

static void timeout_handler_free(void *data)
{
    struct timeout_handler *to_handler = reinterpret_cast<struct timeout_handler *>(data);

    if (to_handler == nullptr)
        return;

    if (to_handler->ev != nullptr) {
        event_del(to_handler->ev);
        event_free(to_handler->ev);
    }

    if (to_handler->dbus_cnx != nullptr)
        dbus_connection_unref(to_handler->dbus_cnx);

    free(to_handler);
}

static void libevent_dispatch_dbus(int fd, short event, void *data)
{
    struct timeout_handler *to_handler = reinterpret_cast<struct timeout_handler *>(data);
    DBusConnection *dbus_cnx = to_handler->dbus_cnx;

    dbus_connection_ref(dbus_cnx);

    while (dbus_connection_dispatch(dbus_cnx) == DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS);

    dbus_connection_unref(dbus_cnx);

    timeout_handler_free(to_handler);
}

static inline void throw_libevent_dispatch_dbus(DBusConnection *dbus_cnx)
{
    const struct timeval timeout = {0,0};
    struct timeout_handler *to_handler = reinterpret_cast<struct timeout_handler *>(calloc(1, sizeof(struct timeout_handler)));
    if (to_handler == nullptr)
        return;

    to_handler->dbus_cnx = dbus_connection_ref(dbus_cnx);

    to_handler->ev = evtimer_new(ev_base, libevent_dispatch_dbus, to_handler);

    evtimer_add(to_handler->ev, &timeout);
}

static void watch_handler_dispatch(int fd, short event, void *data)
{
    struct watch_handler *io_handler = reinterpret_cast<struct watch_handler *>(data);
    DBusDispatchStatus status;
    unsigned int flags = 0;

    dbus_connection_ref(io_handler->dbus_cnx);

    if (evutil_socket_geterror(fd) != 0)
        flags |= DBUS_WATCH_ERROR;

    if (event & EV_READ)
        flags |= DBUS_WATCH_READABLE;
    if (event & EV_WRITE)
        flags |= DBUS_WATCH_WRITABLE;

    dbus_watch_handle(io_handler->watch, flags);

    status = dbus_connection_get_dispatch_status(io_handler->dbus_cnx);
    if (status == DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS)
        throw_libevent_dispatch_dbus(io_handler->dbus_cnx);

    dbus_connection_unref(io_handler->dbus_cnx);
}

static void watch_handler_free(void *data)
{
    struct watch_handler *io_handler = reinterpret_cast<struct watch_handler *>(data);

    if (io_handler == nullptr)
        return;

    if (io_handler->ev != nullptr) {
        event_del(io_handler->ev);
        event_free(io_handler->ev);
    }

    dbus_connection_unref(io_handler->dbus_cnx);

    free(io_handler);
}

static dbus_bool_t libevent_dbus_watch_add(DBusWatch *watch, void *data)
{
    DBusConnection *dbus_cnx = reinterpret_cast<DBusConnection *>(data);
    struct watch_handler *io_handler;
    unsigned int flags;
    short io_condition;
    int io_fd;

    if (dbus_watch_get_enabled(watch) == FALSE)
        return TRUE;

    io_handler = reinterpret_cast<struct watch_handler *>(calloc(1, sizeof(struct watch_handler)));
    if (io_handler == nullptr)
        return FALSE;

    io_handler->dbus_cnx = dbus_connection_ref(dbus_cnx);
    io_handler->watch = watch;

    dbus_watch_set_data(watch, io_handler, watch_handler_free);

    flags = dbus_watch_get_flags(watch);

    io_condition = EV_PERSIST;

    if (flags & DBUS_WATCH_READABLE)
        io_condition |= EV_READ;
    if (flags & DBUS_WATCH_WRITABLE)
        io_condition |= EV_WRITE;

    io_fd = dbus_watch_get_unix_fd(watch);

    io_handler->ev = event_new(ev_base, io_fd, io_condition,
                    watch_handler_dispatch, io_handler);

    event_add(io_handler->ev, nullptr);

    return TRUE;
}

static void libevent_dbus_watch_remove(DBusWatch *watch, void *data)
{
    if (dbus_watch_get_enabled(watch) == TRUE)
        return;

    dbus_watch_set_data(watch, nullptr, nullptr);
}

static void libevent_dbus_watch_toggled(DBusWatch *watch, void *data)
{
    if (dbus_watch_get_enabled(watch) == TRUE)
        libevent_dbus_watch_add(watch, data);
    else
        libevent_dbus_watch_remove(watch, data);
}

static void timeout_handler_dispatch(int fd, short event, void *data)
{
    struct timeout_handler *to_handler = reinterpret_cast<struct timeout_handler *>(data);

    dbus_timeout_handle(to_handler->timeout);
}

static inline void _set_timer(struct timeval *timer, long int milliseconds)
{
    timer->tv_sec = milliseconds / 1000;
    timer->tv_usec = (milliseconds % 1000) * 1000;
}

static dbus_bool_t libevent_dbus_timeout_add(DBusTimeout *timeout, void *data)
{
    struct timeout_handler *to_handler;
    struct timeval timer;

    if (dbus_timeout_get_enabled(timeout) == FALSE)
        return TRUE;

    to_handler = reinterpret_cast<struct timeout_handler *>(calloc(1, sizeof(struct timeout_handler)));
    if (to_handler == nullptr)
        return FALSE;

    dbus_timeout_set_data(timeout, to_handler, timeout_handler_free);

    _set_timer(&timer, dbus_timeout_get_interval(timeout));

    to_handler->ev = evtimer_new(ev_base, timeout_handler_dispatch, to_handler);
    evtimer_add(to_handler->ev, (const struct timeval *) &timer);

    return TRUE;
}

static void libevent_dbus_timeout_remove(DBusTimeout *timeout, void *data)
{
    dbus_timeout_set_data(timeout, nullptr, nullptr);
}

static void libevent_dbus_timeout_toggled(DBusTimeout *timeout, void *data)
{
    if (dbus_timeout_get_enabled(timeout) == TRUE)
        libevent_dbus_timeout_add(timeout, data);
    else
        libevent_dbus_timeout_remove(timeout, data);
}

static void libevent_dbus_dispatch_status(DBusConnection *dbus_cnx,
                DBusDispatchStatus new_status, void *data)
{
    DBusDispatchStatus status;

    if (dbus_connection_get_is_connected(dbus_cnx) == FALSE)
        return;

    status = dbus_connection_get_dispatch_status(dbus_cnx);
    if (status == DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS)
        throw_libevent_dispatch_dbus(dbus_cnx);
}

static dbus_bool_t setup_dbus_in_libevent_mainloop(DBusConnection *dbus_cnx)
{
    DBusDispatchStatus status;

    if (dbus_connection_set_watch_functions(dbus_cnx,
            libevent_dbus_watch_add, libevent_dbus_watch_remove,
            libevent_dbus_watch_toggled, dbus_cnx, nullptr) == FALSE)
        return FALSE;

    if (dbus_connection_set_timeout_functions(dbus_cnx,
            libevent_dbus_timeout_add, libevent_dbus_timeout_remove,
            libevent_dbus_timeout_toggled, dbus_cnx, nullptr) == FALSE)
        return FALSE;

    dbus_connection_set_dispatch_status_function(dbus_cnx,
            libevent_dbus_dispatch_status, dbus_cnx, nullptr);

    status = dbus_connection_get_dispatch_status(dbus_cnx);
    if (status == DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS)
        throw_libevent_dispatch_dbus(dbus_cnx);

    return TRUE;
}

int setup_event_loop_for_dbus(DBusConnection *dbus_cnx)
{
    if (ev_base == nullptr)
        ev_base = event_base_new();
    if (ev_base == nullptr)
        return -1;

    if (setup_dbus_in_libevent_mainloop(dbus_cnx) == FALSE) {
        dbus_connection_unref(dbus_cnx);
        event_base_free(ev_base);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int libevent_run_loop_dbus(void)
{
    return event_base_loop(ev_base, 0);
}


void dbus_cleanup_event_loop(DBusConnection *dbus_cnx)
{
    if (dbus_cnx == nullptr)
        return;

    dbus_connection_set_watch_functions(dbus_cnx,
                        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    dbus_connection_set_timeout_functions(dbus_cnx,
                        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    dbus_connection_set_dispatch_status_function(dbus_cnx,
                            nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Everybody voted for the example above, but this has the correct behavior of calling `dbus_connection_get_dispatch_status()` when you are done setting everything up and then triggering a dispatch `if (status == DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS)`.