# How to use DBusWatch functions to receive asynchronous requests?

Tags: dbus

I've seen the program illustrated in [DBusWatch and DBusTimeout examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378593/dbuswatch-and-dbustimeout-examples), but I don't understand why the following code is used in dispatch() function:

```
while (dbus_connection_get_dispatch_status(c) == DBUS_DISPATCH_DATA_REMAINS)
    dbus_connection_dispatch(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dbus_connection_dispatch()` triggers the top level main loop action in dbus library which in turn will dispatch the steps of actions into other functions. The actual bus message receiving should be in a user handler function.

It can be an example on [the bind9 code by apple](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bind9/bind9-24/bind9/contrib/dbus/dbus_service.c). The message handling is triggered in these steps according to my reading:

- The `select()` returns in the main loop with a `fd` set by the dbus watch.
- The main loop calls `process_watches()` which walks the tree and call `process_watch()`.
- In the end, it looks like the dbus message is handled by a call through

  (*(cs->mf)) ( cs, type, reply, serial, dest, path, member, interface, 0L,
          sender, signature, message, 0L, 0L, 0L, cs->def_mf_obj);

The `cs->mf` should be holding a user handler function added by `dbus_svc_add_filter()`.