# Dbus structure and method calls in C

Tags: c, methods, architecture, dbus, bluez

I am starting to create a dbus application in C to interface with bluez.  I am new to dbus and I am a little confused as how to correctly structure my application with dbus.

The first question is related to the Service, Interface, and Object path in dbus.  [Bluez Adapter API](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt) has the org.bluez service, a org.bluez.Adapter1 interface, and a number of methods and properties.  If I wanted to call the void StopDiscovery() method, would the following be the correct call?

```
DBusPendingCall * pending;
// create a new method call and check for errors
msg = dbus_message_new_method_call("org.bluez",
    "/", // object to call on
    "org.bluez.Adapter1", // interface to call on
    "StopDiscovery"); // method name
// send message and get a handle for a reply
if (!dbus_connection_send_with_reply (m_dbus_conn, msg, &pending, -1))
{
     //err
}
```

If this is the case, when does the object path come into play?

The follow on to this is how to go about receiving information back from dbus.  I've seen a few examples with a DBusPendingCall * however the function has dbus_pending_call_block() so the function blocks until the data is returned.  If I wanted to do multiple calls and not block I would need to make a list of DBPendingCall pointers and check each one?  Are there any callbacks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that both the object path and the interface are required when talking to bluez over dbus.

```
// create a new method call for the adapter
msg = dbus_message_new_method_call("org.bluez",
"/org/bluez/hci0", // object to call on
"org.bluez.Adapter1", // interface to call on
"StopDiscovery"); // method name


// create a new method call for a characteristic on
// a given service 
msg = dbus_message_new_method_call("org.bluez",
"/org/bluez/hci0/dev_12_34_56_78_9A_BC/service0010/char0011",
"org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1",
"StartNotify");
```

The select on Unix sockets for pending looks like a solid, scaleable way to go, I will consider this architecture as the application grows

Answer (score 2):

I did create [an example showing the non-blocking call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32930566/362754) based on the dbus watch and timeout mechanism, in response to the SO question [dbus watch and timeout examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378593/dbuswatch-and-dbustimeout-examples). Basically you run a unix select() loop and everything is dispatched around it.

And I did not touch the multiple outstanding pending-call part. I assume one way is to check each pending-call to see whether it is completed when the watched event is received. Checking pending complete is non-blocking. If you keep a small number of outstanding pending calls it should be ok, though that is not an efficient solution if the number becomes big.

It looks like according to the API document, a better solution is to use `dbus_pending_call_set_notify()` to register a callback to a pending call.